# how to get quotes in output in unix?

Tags: linux, unix

abc.dat file contains lines

```
1
2
3
```

code is

```
tradeline=""
for line in $(cat abc.dat)
do
tradeline="$line,$tradeline"
done
```

sample output am getting is 1,2,3,
but i want the output as "1","2","3",

can u help me plz

Comment: Your solution should generate '3,2,1,' rather than '1,2,3,'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems, the first being what you describe.

It will also put the numbers in reverse order and have a trailing comma, which is probably not what you want.

If that *is* what you want, just use the second solution.

Solution 1, right order and no trailing comma:

```
tradeline=""
sep=""
for line in $(cat abc.dat) ; do
    tradeline="${tradeline}${sep}\"${line}\""
    sep=","
done
echo ${tradeline}
```

Solution 2, right order with trailing comma:

```
tradeline=""
for line in $(cat abc.dat) ; do
    tradeline="${tradeline}\"${line}\","
done
echo ${tradeline}
```

Solution 3, much simpler, using tools meant for the job:

```
awk 'BEGIN {sep=""} {printf "%s\"%s\"",sep,$0;sep=","} END {print}' abc.dat
```

Solution 3 would be my preferred option since it'll be faster *and* be able to handle input lines with white space in them.

Comment: actually i used some othe command to trim the last character after getting tradeline before.

but ur frst solution gives me everything without comma in the last
thank u..............

Answer (score 3):

Escape the quotes with `\`:

```
tradeline="\"$line\",$tradeline"
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that using `cat` like that will mean that if you have several words on one line, you will still quote each word separately.  Also, your code will generate '3,2,1' rather than '1,2,3'.

To get quotes around each line, you would need to use the `read` command:

```
tradeline=""
sep=""
cat abc.dat |
while read line
do
    tradeline="$tradeline$sep\"$line\""
    sep=","
done
```

This is quite similar to Pax's solution - except for the use of `read` to obtain each line.